# What version of Minecraft works on an Asus T100?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm looking at the Asus T100 for a homework laptop for my daughter, but is she going to be able to play the full version of Minecraft game on it?  I know about computers but don't know anything about Minecraft - she tells me playing it on an iPad is like a cut down version and she prefers playing it on our current PC.  I have a horrible feeling an Asus hybrid laptop is only going to give her the iPad version of the game, is that right?

Comment: The base question being asked here is a misunderstanding between Minecraft Pocket Edition, and the full version of Minecraft.  Answers should be answering that, not whether or not a specific laptop can run the game, as that is off-topic.  I've edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements   (Here are Minecraft's system requirements)

Answer (score 6):

There are multiple versions of Minecraft, the original (full) version is the PC version, there are also versions for mobile devices (like the iPad) that don't have all the features of PC Minecraft.

The ASUS T100 is a laptop which runs Windows, so it can in theory run the PC version of Minecraft. It should run it decently well given the hardware in the device, there are videos of people running it on [youtube for example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdNfIEJgN54)

Comment: The t100 Runs Windows RT, Windows RT has no support for Java at the moment, there are some emulators avaiable but those are very badly programed. therefore it's nearly immposibile to run minecraft full version

Comment: @codermaster I can't find any reference of the T100 running windows RT, everything I can find points to windows 8.1, even the [asus site itself](http://www.asus.com/uk/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TA/). SO that seems like proof enough to me.

Comment: Heck, even the ASUS site @Arperum linked shows a bunch of games being playable, including Minecraft (for some reason the marketing department messed up and included a XBox360 Minecraft image but eh, whatever).

Comment: I might have been wrong about that but check the site, scroll down until you see Enchant your entertainment or something like that. look at the picture and tel mee what you see, minecraft Xbox edition, That's is not the full game and is based on PE

Comment: Jeah, and that won't run on any version of windows, anyway this is probably getting a bit long for the comments, wanna take it over to a chat? :)

Comment: No I think you're right but still you have to admit that the T100 isen't the best option for playing minecraft. even in the price range.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will definitely run the full version of Minecraft, since the Asus T100 is a laptop and runs on the full version of Windows (10).

However, given that the specs for T100 is not as powerful as its other cousins, gameplay quality may not be as good.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, seeing the Asus T100 runs Windows RS, It is probebly not possible to play minecraft at all, because minecraft PE (the downcutted version) is only avaiable for Android 3.0+ or Ios 6+. for the full version you want to have an actual running any kind of windows XP or up. or any of the last 3 generations of macbooks. Also ubuntu, and ubuntu based linux OS's, will run minecraft

Comment: Back to google for me then!  Many thanks, for the clear info - I gather Minecraft Pocket Edition is the version she isn't so keen on.

Comment: Correct the Windows RT can play only the Pocket Edition (PE for future reference's)

Comment: [The Asus T100 has windows 8.1](http://www.asus.com/uk/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T100TA/), and can run the "full" game. No pocket edition or the like.

Comment: Why does my friend need emulators for it them then?

Comment: Some other comment, could you please mention windows vista/7 or up in your post (win XP might actually work, but using that is a terrible plan)

Comment: Please check your site , scroll down until you spot the title Enchant your entertainment or something like that. look at the picture and tel mee what you see, minecraft Xbox edition, That's is not the full game and is based on PE.

Comment: your where right about xp though..